# Postgres - Return error on update if record not found

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering if there is a way of getting an error back on update if the row does not exist in the database when I issue an update.

```
update users set email='aa@bb.com' where id=200
```

If users table does not have user with id=200, then postgres simply says "UPDATE 0". However, I am wondering if I can get an error back. That way, I don't have to issue 2 requests to the database, once to check existence, once to update. There could also be a race condition between checking the existence and issuing an update if we do it separately.

Why do I need an error? Simple - so the clients know they have used an invalid user id and they take corrective action.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. If the record does not exist, what action do you want to take? Insert a new record, or simply inform the user / redirect to a login page?

Comment: Its an update statement. So the clients were expecting the record to be there. But perhaps it got deleted before the client issued the update. The client that issued the update should be notified the record does not exist. No need to insert any new record.

Comment: Rather than trowing an exception it's probably much more efficient to simply check the number of updated rows within your programming language (as Igor suggested)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use something like

```
update users set email='aa@bb.com' where id=200 returning id;
```

This query will return the `id` of the updated row. If it returns 0 rows - then throw an error in your application.

Also you may want to check if your db driver / framework returns the count of affected rows (like `getUpdateCount()` in JDBC).

Comment: Sounds like a more efficient solution. Will this also work with multiple row updates?

Comment: @BVSat Yes. It will return `id` of all updated rows. Check the documentation for details and examples: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Answer (score 13):

You can use an anonymous code block.

```
do $$
begin
    update users set email='aa@bb.com' where id=200;
    if not found then raise exception 'User not found';
    end if;
end $$;
```

Or regular function:

```
create or replace function update_user(new_email text, user_id integer)
returns void language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    update users set email = new_email where id = user_id;
    if not found then raise exception 'User id % not found', user_id;
    end if;
end $$;    

select update_user('aa@example.com', 200);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot. Anyway to generalize this so we don't have to write this for all tables? For example, how could we change the error message to singularize the table name instead of "User" in "User not found". Can we make this a function? Or, can we make this the default action for update commands across the board for all tables in a particular schema?

Comment: You sholud replace every update query with anonymous code block like in the answer.